# How can I add a counter in android, whenever I press a button the counter increments by one

Tags: android, counter

kindly, i am saving internal file and reading it after that using file input/output stream respectively.
I want during saving to add a counter that every time I press save the counter increments by one.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the activity level counter and increment its value. In case you need to persist it, do that onPause and retriave it back on onResumt using shared preferences.